# How to filter by date in file openFileDialog | VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

So, I have a program where you can load settings from using the Windows Explorer, opened by calling openFileDialog.

By default, all the files get filtered by their name. Can I make it so that upon clicking on 'load settings' and opening the file selector, it defaults to sorting by date created or modified?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: That's not an option.  Most users will know how to click the "Date modified" column to sort by date.  Very much a way to organize the list that you should always leave up to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible using Windows API calls, but the solution would be pretty ugly.

See [this link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?443285-OpenFileDialog-file-sorting) for more info

Comment: Damn, that's some ugly stuff.. Thanks for the link, I'll try and implement it!